# getting more details when SpringWebFlux returns 400

Tags: java, rest, spring-webflux

I made a GET web service with Spring web flux.
Code is something like that.

```
     @GetMapping("/url/{reportingDate}")
     public ResponseEntity<String> webservice(
     @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") final LocalDate reportingDate) {

         // some code
         return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
     }
```

Then, instead of making this call (OK)

```
 request GET 'http://localhost:8080/url/2022-03-10'
```

I voluntarily make this one

```
 request GET 'http://localhost:8080/url/20220310'
```

how does it make Spring returns to me  "400 bad request" with absolutely no detail in the payload? (i would have expected here some details regarding my bad date format)

Any idea?

Comment: You can try changing the log configuration to Trace or Debug: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Comment: no, i don't want logs but really want Spring to return error messages to the remote API user.

Comment: Please provide a fully working example

Comment: all is in my first post. web service, via Spring, returns no payload. i know why but remote user will not. that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i found it.

using this makes the job.

```
  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String illegalArgument(final IllegalArgumentException exception) 
  {
       return exception.getMessage();
  }
```

then, the web service returns to me..

```
 Parse attempt failed for value [20220310]
```